# Get Number Of Running Processes By Name In Bash

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Suppose I run the following in terminal:

```
pgrep Google Chrome
```

and it produces the following output of all the PID's:

```
110
311
142
```

How could I display exactly how many processes have been listed without counting myself to produce something like:

```
110
311
142

There are currently 3 processes running under the application 'Google Chrome'
```

Comment: `pgrep 'Google Chrome' | wc -l`

Comment: top | grep google chrome | uniq something like this wokrs ?

Answer (score 1):

I find wrapper functions quite helpful for this kind of thing:

```sh
pgrep() {
  local app=${!#} pids
  # now invoke the *command* pgrep and
  # capture the output into an array of lines
  readarray -t pids < <(command pgrep "$@")
  # print the output
  printf "%s\n" "${pids[@]}"
  # and print the summary
  printf "\nThere are currently %d processes running under the application '%s'\n" \
    "${#pids[@]}" \
    "$app"
}
```

This also lets you use pgrep options, like `pgrep -fl "Google Chrome"`

The problem is that pgrep allows you to specify multiple patterns, and this function only captures the last one as "the application."

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce the output in the format you specified:

```
proc="Google Chrome"

pids=$(pgrep "$proc")
if [[ -n $pids ]]; then
    printf "%s\n\nThere are currently %d processes running under the application '%s'\n" \
        "$pids" "$(wc -l <<< "$pids")" "$proc"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command :

```
pgrep -c <process name>
```

Example :

```
pgrep -c chromium
```